# Subsequent property declarations must have the same type

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js

I have two `webpack` config files

webpack1.config.js

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: [
        './app/App1/App1.ts'
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('', 'web/assets/js'),
        filename: 'app1.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".vue", ".js"],
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./app'),
            path.resolve('./node_modules')
        ],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue?$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    esModule: true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

webpack2.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: [
        './app/App2/App2.ts'
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('', 'web/assets/js'),
        filename: 'app2.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".vue", ".js"],
        modules: [
            path.resolve('./app'),
            path.resolve('./node_modules')
        ],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue?$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    esModule: true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Now, when I compile `app1` using `webpack1.config.js` it throws an error **Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'user' must be of type 'IUser', but here has type 'IUser'.**

Because in `App1.ts` I have the following line

```
   import IUser from 'IUser'; // /app/App1/IUser.ts
   ...
   user:IUser;
   ...
```

And `App2.ts` has

```
   import IUser from 'IUser'; // /app/App2/IUser.ts
   ...
   user:IUser;
   ...
```

The problem is that location `app/App2` also contains `IUser` interface but how can I tell in `webpack1.config.js` to **stop** looking at `app/App2` locations?

I already tried something like

``

```
           test: /\.ts?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: [/node_modules/, /app\/App2/], // so maybe try to omit App2?
            options: {
                appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
            }
```

So I tried to exclude `app/App2` but it did not help and I still see that error.
I have the latest version of TypeScript and funny because it was working all the time fine and suddenly this error came out today (I did not update anything, just tried to compile the project like I usually do).

Comment: maybe the exclude app should be a string instead? so `"/app/App2"` Otherwise it's a regex and might be only matching the immediate folder that's named `app/App2`  rather than the actual path

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this as well unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: hmm, then maybe `path.resolve(__dirname, '/App2')`